# how to use flexible in listview in flutterr?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make backgroundcolor different from Flexible area to the end of the Listview , but I guess it's in the listview so can't apply.. how can I make backgroundcolor different after the Text(my Identification)?

```
body:
  ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),  
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: [
  Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        
  
      ),
      Container(
        
          
      ),
      Container(
        
      ),
      Container(
          
      ),
      Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        child: Row(
          children:[
            Text("My Identification"),
        ]
      )

      ),
      Flexible(
        fit: FlexFit.loose,
        child: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                cardWidget("card1", "drivelisence"),
                cardWidget("card2", "IdCard"),
                cardWidget("card3",   "deploma")
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )),
    ],
    
  )
    
      ]
  )
```

Comment: What's your expected output any ui images available?

Comment: could you please include the ui image you want to achive?

Answer (score 1):

actually I am afraid you can't using your widgets the `ListView` has unbounded height so you can not use flexible widgets because it will expand to infinity
Way to use `Expanded` inside `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView`,wrap the widget with `CustomScrollView` and you’re able to use `expanded` inside scrollable widgets.

```
CustomScrollview( 
  slivers: [
  SliverFillRemaining(
   hasscrollBody: false,
    child: Column(
      children: [
       Container(
      
       ),
     Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 100,
      child: Row(
       children:[
        Text("My Identification"),
       ]
     )
   ),
   Flexible(
    fit: FlexFit.loose,
    child: Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            cardWidget("card1", "drivelisence"),
            cardWidget("card2", "IdCard"),
            cardWidget("card3",   "deploma")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )),
    ]
   ), // Column
```

Comment: Thankyou.  now it's possible to change color in flexible widget.